# Listing places according to distance from the user's position?

Tags: android, dictionary, android-maps

I am developing an android app (supporting 2.2 to 4.4). In it, I hold a bunch of places details with latitude and longitude. What I want to do is to list these places in the order of which comes nearest to the position of user.

**My current project status**

1. Getting user position = DONE
2. Sorting places per user's position (nearest place first) and list them = **UNDONE** (here I need help)
3. Putting the intent to map after getting the user's position and nearby places (which is selected by user from list) = DONE

I've done a lot of research in the past 16 days through Google. But all I could find was *Google Places*. Unfortunately it only supports fixed keywords like BANK, HOSPITAL, POLICE, etc.

Comment: I haven't used Google Maps API myself, but can't you get directions from the user's position to each of the places (along with distance) and sorting according to the distances of directions?

Comment: So you have the coordinate of the user and the coordinates of your the places ?

Comment: Do you need the distance by air or by foot ? (I mean do you need to take into account the streets ?)

Comment: Yes i have all coordinates of my places , and coordinates from users will lively fetched by gps or by network . So i could say i have both coordinates. if i took distance by air it will be that much accurate , so i prefer by foot . Because most of my users will be using public transport. @  frouil

Comment: ya im trying that way too by creating data base , if i could find something like google place it will be much easier @   Mahm00d

Answer (score 0):

Use this library to calculate distances of each point.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/#spherical

**computeDistanceBetween()**

Returns the distance, in meters, between two latitude/longitude coordinates.

Then sort the points on their distance.